Is it possible to load Linux kernel code to a specific NUMA node when booting?
I'm doing a benchmark in Linux kernel. I want to make sure all the benchmarked kernel code is stored in the same NUMA node as the CPU that runs the code. I implement a system call to trigger the execution of the benchmarked kernel code, so I can specify the CPU to run the benchmarked code by binding CPU in userspace. However, I cannot guarantee the kernel code is stored in the same NUMA node as the CPU that runs the benchmark. I wonder is there any way that I can force Linux kernel code to be loaded in a specific NUMA node during the booting process. I've searched The kernel’s command-line parameters document using "numa" as a keyword, but did not find a useful parameter. I'd be very grateful if anyone can help :)
